# Web3j v3.3.1 : Error while generating compiled solidity smart contracts which returns array of struct

Tags: java, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am returning an array of struct from solidity function as below.

**pragma solidity ^0.4.21;**

**pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;**

**function  getPurchaseOrderForVendor(string vendorNameInput) constant returns (PurchaseOrderStruct[])**

It is compiled to abi and bin files. The issue is with creating wrapper files for the contract using web3j(v3.3.1). Im getting the below errors.

```
Generating com.contract.InvoiceSettlement_sol_InvoiceSettlement ... 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Unsupported type
encountered: tuple
    at org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.AbiTypes.getType(AbiTypes.java:221)

    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapper.buildTypeName(SolidityFunct
ionWrapper.java:851)
    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapper.buildTypeNames(SolidityFunc
tionWrapper.java:508)
    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapper.buildFunction(SolidityFunct
ionWrapper.java:523)
    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapper.buildFunctionDefinitions(So
lidityFunctionWrapper.java:216)
    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapper.generateJavaFiles(SolidityF
unctionWrapper.java:112)
    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapper.generateJavaFiles(SolidityF
unctionWrapper.java:94)
    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.generate(SolidityF
unctionWrapperGenerator.java:123)
    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.main(SolidityFunct
ionWrapperGenerator.java:87)
    at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.run(SolidityFuncti
onWrapperGenerator.java:48)
    at org.web3j.console.Runner.main(Runner.java:38)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solidity does not support returning structs in external calls. It is only allowed in `internal` function calls. You need to decompose the struct and return the elements via a tuple.

Source: [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/frequently-asked-questions.html#can-a-contract-function-return-a-struct)

Comment: i tried the decomposed way. but i am not able to return string array(my struct contains a element with string as its type).

Comment: You need to either return strings as `bytes32`, or (my preferred approach) you use one function to return the size of the array you want and have your retrieval function take in an index parameter and return one decomposed struct element at a time. This approach is cleaner and avoids possible out of gas exceptions in cases where your array is large.

Comment: On the same note, if you have a public variable with struct, you will get this error too. i.e. mapping(uint256 => SomeStruct) public somemapping.